# OnStartupComplete is not call in clients environment

Tags: c#, vsto, visio, office-addins

I have a Visio add-in.
After upgrading to .Net 4 (from 3.5) in the clients environment OnStartupComplete is not called after OnConnection.
but in development environment everything works fine.

```
 public void OnConnection(object application, Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom)
 public void OnStartupComplete(ref System.Array custom)
```

I'm pretty sure that there is no exception in OnConnection.

The add-in does not go to Inactive state.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you installed all the required prerequsites on the problematic PC. Note, the full edition of the .Net framework should be installed (not the Client Profile). Also I'd suggest checking the Trust Center setting on the PC. The macro security settings can be applied to add-ins as well.

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again.

You can read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article.

Finally, you may try to use the Fuslogvw.exe utility to diagnose assembly binding in .Net. See [Fuslogvw.exe and diagnosing .NET assembly binding issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2006/07/12/663834.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi Eugene

Thank you for your response.

In hard and soft disabling add-in should go to Inactive or Disable state.

In my case it's still in Active state.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with a newly created add-in?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to debug this issue is calling OnStartupComplete  from OnConnection manually to find out what's wrogn.

in my case there was a difference between some types and interfaces so when it wants to load some types that used in OnStartupComplete before starting a first line of OnStartupComplete it gets that the "method does not have an implementation".